# How can I get rid of a image in an li using jquery?

Tags: jquery, slider, html-lists

I'm trying to install a slider in Rapidweaver and I would like to display only slides 1 and 2 on a particular page.  I'm still pretty new at this, so anything could help.  So, how can I remove slide 3 by using jquery?

```
<ul id="unoslider" class="unoslider">
 <li id="slide1"><img src="images/banner_1.jpg"  /></li>
 <li id="slide2"><img src="images/banner_2.jpg"  /></li>
 <li id="slide3"><img src="images/banner_3.jpg"  /></li>
</ul>
```

Please, help me!

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3):

To remove it from the DOM:

```
$('#unoslider #slide3').remove();
```

Set it's display to "`hidden`":

```
$('#unoslider #slide3').hide();
```

Comment: Xander the remove script worked great in removing the image, but there's still a white slide in lieu of the image.  I wonder what's going on.  Thanks for you help!

Comment: this could should `remove` or `hide` the `li` respectively. given the code you've provided i wouldn't be able to pinpoint your other issue, "white slide."

Comment: Xander I contacted the person that created the slideshow and he told me to do this: "You could use a jQuery DOM functions to remove the concrete LI, destroy the unoslider object, and then reinitialize the unoslider again."  I'm still really new, so does this make any sense to you?